# How to set a Version Name in C#?

Tags: c#, version

What is the best way to set a Version Name - not just a Number - in an C#-Project?

The AssemblyVersion- and the AssemblyFileVersion-Attribute can only set version Numbers.

Comment: what you mean by version name?

Comment: Then use `AssemblyDescription` or `AssemblyTitle` for your name? I don't exactly get what you ask.

Comment: Our (main) Versions have Names in addition to version numbers. They are called: "Wallersee" (for version 1.0.0.0), "Irrsee" (for version 1.1.0.0) and so on...(The names are the names of different lakes in Austria)

Comment: @Gener4tor then use `AssemblyFileVersion`. You can use text in it. Obviously because there are `.` in the version name

Comment: @sLw: This produces a "error CS7034: The specified version string does not conform to the required format - major[.minor[.build[.revision]]]" because I treat warnings as errors...I could supress this warning, but this does not seem to be the optimal way...